# Replace N/A values with values in a corresponding values and a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace NaN values in one column with values in another column and a string. Sample:

```
    date_added  release_year
4   NaN         2019
```

I want to replace NaN values in the 'date_added' column with the string 'January 1, {release_year}'. I tried to use the following code:

```
for i in df.index:
    df['date_added'].fillna('January 1, {}'.format(df.loc[i, 'release_year']), inplace = True)
```

However, the result seems not correct:

```
        date_added        release_year
5339    January 1, 2019   2016
```

Anybody can provide me with a solution for this?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

The method `fillna()` iterates over the row indeces, so you don't need to use `for` loop. In your case only the first iteration of the loop does something, after that there is no NaNs anymore. Try this:

```
df['date_added'].fillna(df['release_year'].apply(lambda x: f'January 1, {x}'), inplace = True)
```

Or this (does the same):

```
df['date_added'].fillna('January 1, ' + df['release_year'].astype(str), inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date_added': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                        'release_year': [2015, 2019, 2018]})
print(df)

   date_added  release_year
0         NaN          2015
1         NaN          2019
2         NaN          2018

df['date_added'] = df['date_added'].fillna('January 1, ' + (df['release_year']).astype(str))

print(df)

        date_added  release_year
0  January 1, 2015          2015
1  January 1, 2019          2019
2  January 1, 2018          2018
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df['date_added'] = np.where(df['date_added'].isnull(), 'January 1 ' + df['release_year'].astype(str),
                            df['date_added'])


       date_added  release_year
0  January 1 2019          2019
1     21 Sep 2021          2021
2  January 1 2022          2022
```